# Append radio checked to the form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

im working on a small app but i cant resolve this
im trying to use jQuery to append checked radio to the form , i did try alot of solution but i did fail
i wrote the code here , hope someone can help me to resolve this issue

```
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios" value="interior">
        Interior
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios" value="exterior">
        Exterior
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios" value="interio+exterior">
        Interior si exterior
    </label>
</div>
```

Here data was fetchted using json and i have the right result

```
 <script>
        $.each(data, function (k, v) {

                        typdespal = v.typdespal;
                        // the problem is that always i cant get the radio checked in the right position from the database
                       // $('#optionsRadios').val(typdespal);
                        $("input:radio[name='optionsRadios']").val(typdespal).prop( "checked", true );;

        </script>
```

Comment: it's working here but http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/bff35obo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to find the correct radio button with value then set its property to checked.

```
$("input:radio[name='optionsRadios']").filter(function(){
   return $(this).val() === typdespal
}).prop( "checked", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to wrap this all in a Document.Ready call. Then you need to only apply the checked function to the checkbox which contains the appropriate value. At the minute you are setting the value of all `optionsRadios`. You can do this with the `prop` [function overload](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function):

```
$(function() { // DOM ready
    $("input:radio[name='optionsRadios']").prop("checked", function() {
       // Only set the checked value when this checkbox value === the corresponding data value
       var val = $(this).val();
       return val === data[val].typdespal;
    });
});
```

Note: I *think* I'm reading your data object right, hard to tell without seeing it :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, several radio buttons may have same name, but not ID. So make them unique. Secondly, try to change your selector to:

```
 $("input:radio[value='"+typdespal+"']").prop( "checked", true );
```